# Covariance of a stochastic integral and a riemann integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Right now, I want to figure out the covariance of a stochastic integral and a riemann integral in the following form:

$$E\left(\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]ds \cdot \int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]dW(s)\right).$$
where $B(\cdot)$ and $W(\cdot)$ are independent Brownian motions, or $d\langle B, W \rangle_t = \gamma dt$.

My guess to this is 0 and my calculation is

$$E\left(\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]ds \cdot \int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]dW(s)\right) = E\left(\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(r)]dr dW(s)\right) = 0 $$
by virtue of $E(\int \cdot dW) = 0$. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you can't simply pull the Riemann integral inside the stochastic integral ... certain measurability issues with that.

Comment: Then what tool can I use to evaluate this product of two integrals?

Comment: What is $(B_t)_t$? A Brownian motion which is independent of $(W_t)_t$.....?

Comment: Yes, you can take it as a Brownian motion independent of W(t). Actually, I am also curious about the case where B(t) is correlated with W(t).